# Bitcoin Core version >0.10 only works with RPC sync

Tags: node.js, bitcoin, bitcoind

I am using [Insight Bitpay](https://insight.bitpay.com/). I am getting this error *"Bitcoin Core version >0.10 only works with RPC sync"* when I start insight. Its telling me to add environmental variable like *"Set the env variable INSIGHT_FORCE_RPC_SYNC = 1"*, but I am stuck here. I tried adding it to `.bashrc`, but it didn't resolve problem.

How do I resolve the problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute "source ~/.bashrc" after you added env variable